# I got CvException by bitmapToMat on android

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm using opencv for android.
but I got same messages from released android app. that is

```
CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/reports/ci/slave_desktop/50-SDK/opencv/modules
/java/generator/src/cpp/utils.cpp:33: error: (-215) info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGBA_8888
|| info.format == ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565 in function void
Java_org_opencv_android_Utils_nBitmapToMat2(JNIEnv*, jclass, jobject, jlong, jboolean)]
    at org.opencv.android.Utils.nBitmapToMat2(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(Utils.java:93)
    at org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(Utils.java:102)
```

I don't know What is wrong and How to fix it.
Let me know please.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your input bitmap is not in either 4 byte 8888 format or 2 byte 565 format so you need to look at how you create your bitmap.

Is it loaded from a file or through the android Camera?

In some devices the bitmap is in YUV format when taken from the Camera so you will need to convert to RGBA first.